# Merging data from several columns

Tags: excel, matlab, optimization, merge

I have a script that does the following: I have an Excel spreadsheet with three columns of Chlorophyll concentrations and sometimes more. Eg. 1) WholeFluro 2) WholeHPLC 3) Net1Fluro but not all three columns have all 3 datasets. For instance, I often have WholeFluro and WholeHPLC OR just Net1Fluro. In order to have more data I like to merge all the data into one data column. In addition I also have the corresponding locations in the ocean where I collected the data from as well as the depths in the water column from where my sample was draw.

I have a MATLAB script that I use for this but it’s very long and it takes me long to use it for different types of data that I want to merge. I was wondering if I could get some help to make it more efficient as it would also help me learn to write better scripts.

My script is as follows:

```
% go to the data folder
    cd C:\Users\Documents\CHLOROPHYLL_DATA_PROCESSED\
    filename = 'Knorr-Working_SizeFracNew.xlsx';
    [num,txt,raw] = xlsread(filename);

% Pick out the relevant data that you need from the large spreadsheet
%Use Raw only to get header info because I can see the header info that I %cannot see in ‘num’
% Use ‘num’ to get actual data
    FracsData=num(:,[1:2:7 8:2:17 19:23 24 29 34]);
    FracsHeaderInfo=raw(:,[1:2:7 8:2:17 19:23 24 29 34]);

%%
% choose the various Chlorophyll data from the large spreadsheet that I want %to merge 
% Here I want to Merge the two columns which have Whole, two columns with
 % Net1, two columns with % Net2 and two columns with Net3

    WholeFluro=FracsData(:,6);
    WholeHPLC=FracsData(:,10);

    Net1Fluro=FracsData(:,7);
    Net1HPLC=FracsData(:,15);

    Net2Fluro=FracsData(:,8);
    Net2HPLC=FracsData(:,16);

    Net3Fluro=FracsData(:,9);
    Net3HPLC=FracsData(:,17);

%%
%Replace NaNs with -999 or I get an error when NaNs from various columns %clash 

    WholeFluro(isnan(WholeFluro))=-999;
    WholeHPLC(isnan(WholeHPLC))=-999;

    Net1Fluro(isnan(Net1Fluro))=-999;
    Net1HPLC(isnan(Net1HPLC))=-999;

    Net2Fluro(isnan(Net2Fluro))=-999;
    Net2HPLC(isnan(Net2HPLC))=-999;

    Net3Fluro(isnan(Net3Fluro))=-999;
    Net3HPLC(isnan(Net3HPLC))=-999;

% Here I create 4 variables that will hold my merged data for whole, N1, N2, % & N3 that are equal to the % the original data
    MergedDataWhole = WholeFluro;
    MergedDataN1 = Net1Fluro;
    MergedDataN2 = Net2Fluro;
    MergedDataN3 = Net3Fluro;

%find the empty places and fill them up with the HPLC data at points x – I %give HPLC data precedence

    x=find(MergedDataWhole==-999);
    MergedDataWhole(x)=WholeHPLC(x);

    x=find(MergedDataN1==-999);
    MergedDataN1(x)=Net1HPLC(x);

    x=find(MergedDataN2==-999);
    MergedDataN2(x)=Net2HPLC(x);

    x=find(MergedDataN3==-999);
    MergedDataN3(x)=Net3HPLC(x);
        MergedDataALL=horzcat(MergedDataWhole,MergedDataN1,MergedDataN2,MergedDataN3);
    MergedDataALL(MergedDataFracs<0)=0;


    outputfilename = 'Merged.xlsx';
    [suc,msg] = xlswrite(outputfilename,Merged);
```

Comment: Why not use excel's programming (VBA). Would probably be quicker.

Comment: Can you not just use Excel formulae for this? Can you describe your merging algorithm please

Comment: I think your question is more suitable to http://codereview.stackexchange.com/. However I think you could benefit from profiling your script to see where the bottlenecks are (regarding performance)

Comment: Would you mind showing a sample input data and your desired output from that?

Comment: Thank you very much for all your comments.  @Luuklag I really want to stick to Matlab and learn it well because my colleagues all use it

Comment: @brodoll thanks for this new link which I did not know about

Comment: @smlq I am posting an example - sorry i should have done it earlier.

Comment: I am sorry but I cant figure out how to make columns of data even though i have tried to follow the help.

Comment: @fatima55. Okay please upload the sample Excel file somewhere so that I can run your code. I hope I can work it out.

Comment: | Wholefluro | WholeHPLC | WholeMerged |
|------------|-----------|-------------|
| 0.14       | NaN       | 0.14        |
| 0.45       | 0.88      | 0.88        |
| NaN        | 0.55      | 0.55        |

Comment: @smlq i have tried ever which way and finally copy pasted the output from http://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables but i have problems creating a line break even tho i use the two spaces specified in the Help. I really dont know how else to post a table although I have hunted around. Thanks a lot!!!!!

Comment: @fatima55 Go to this link: http://www.filedropper.com/index.php and upload your `Knorr-Working_SizeFracNew.xlsx` file or a minimal sample of it. After uploading, click the `2. share your personal link` in that webpage. Copy paste that link here.

Comment: @smlq thank you very much. I am sharing  the link below. http://www.filedropper.com/stackoverflowexample When i merge i give preference to data with 'HPLC', and if not then "fluro' and if both are not available then 'WellsMeyer'